# Русские слова с маленькой буквы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте. Как выразить регулярное выражение, отсевающее русские слова, начинающиеся с маленькой буквы?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$string = "Здравствуйте, помогите написать регулярное выражение отсевающее Русские слова начинающиеся с маленькой буквы.";
$pattern = '/(^|\s|\b)+[^А-Я]+/u';
echo preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $string);
```